# Get List PropertyBag value using GraphAPI

Tags: sharepoint-online

I know we can get/set `PropertyBag` values on List level using CSOM and other ways. However, I wanted to know if there is any way to this using Graph API

I checked below documentation and don't see anything related

[Get metadata for a list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs)

Is there way to use Expand parameter and get the value.

We have application already in place that relies on Graph APi through AD APP . Hence would like to leverage graph api to read a property bag value set by another application.

I am looking specifically for List level property bag values. Kindly advise if you have any ideas please.

Answer (score 1):

For example, we can use the Graph API below to get the list name.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}?$select=name
```

All the list properties in the Graph API as screenshot below.

[image]

Refer to: [List resource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)